# What is a word for being bored but with lots to do?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I can't find a word to fit the state of being **bored but with lots to do** - ultimately lacking motivation to do (tedious, repetitive) work, when one feels one should be motivated due to the amount of work needed to do.

Neither indifferent (*having no particular interest or sympathy*) nor frustrated (*feeling or expressing distress and annoyance resulting from an inability to change or achieve something*) seem to fit the desired word, although both are relevant.

It's not that the work actively causes the boredom, but is instead a factor relating to the frustration.

Sources: Oxford Dictionary

Comment: you mean, bored because you have lots to do, or bored despite lots to do?

Comment: Please clarify your question and make a sample sentence where the word could be used.

Comment: @Josh  *bored but with lots to do* means he is definitely bored despite lots to do. It is like saying *I want ice cream, but with chocolate sprinkles*. Like I'd settle for just one sprinkle. :)

Comment: @vickyace if he is bored *despite* having lots to do, and not bored *because* he has lots to do, maybe the definition of "blasé" would not be appropriate? It seems to depend on the latter interpretation.

Comment: Then perhaps I should wait.

Comment: Bored *despite* lots to do.  I'd use it as in '*I'm ___*' (bored despite lots to do).

Comment: It may help for you to explain the link between your boredom and the work. For example, is the work *causing* you to be bored? If the work wasn't there, would you be bored anyway (i.e. you were already bored - the fact that there's lots to do is irrelevant)? When you say *bored*, are you board of the work, or is it used as a synonym for a medical condition such as ADD/ADHD?

Comment: Perhaps the work to be done is not challenging and completely uninteresting and it’s therefore difficult to get motivated?

Comment: @Lawrence the work isn't necessarily linked to the boredom, just that despite having so much to do, I don't have the desire to do anything.  The work that needs to be done is tiresome, and monotonous as Jim says

Comment: If you're lacking motivation to do the things you should do, you are ***unmotivated*** or possibly ***uninspired***.

Comment: @1006a, yes, but in this context I'd say "I'm so uninspired to do this ...'  I'd like to negate the extra clause, and end up with "I'm so ___".  I suppose this is so uninspirational might do...

Comment: @Lawrence - Guessing from my own (current!) experience: lots of work to do, no motivation (due to work being either too difficult or too repetitive), spend the day on SE until I'm bored of SE... but still don't want to do my work. (Here's hoping my employer doesn't read this... ho hum). If the work wasn't there I'd still be bored because I need to be in the office to give the appearance of work, and I can't do things like play on my games console at my desk.

Comment: @AndyT precisely.  I suppose it's a bit of a *monday morning feeling* but without the time specificity...

Comment: It sounds like you might [have the blues](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have-the-blues), specifically, the [Monday blues](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jacquelynsmith/2013/02/25/11-ways-to-beat-the-monday-blues/#517909a823f5).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like frustration is making someone feel like a [***burnout***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burnout).

> exhaustion of physical or emotional strength or motivation usually as
>   a result of prolonged stress or frustration

On the other hand, one might be [***disaffected***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disaffected) if their frustration with their work situation has led them to resent authority.

This might lead them to become [***disengaged***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disengaged) or detached from their work - they might have plenty of work to go around, but they aren't interested.

Comment: You can also refer to them as "burned out," if you don't want to use the noun form.

Comment: I don't think disaffected is what I want to use here - it's not exactly authority I'm frustrated with.  I suppose disengaged is more appropriate, but it implies they are doing something else, eg "The students were disengaged today; they were flying paper aeroplanes all lesson"

Comment: By the way, the correct form for quotes is a `> ` rather than four spaces.  See the blockquote section of [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, your expansion of the question does not match the question itself. Sometimes, when one is looking for a word, the depiction of what the word expresses is difficult precisely because the word doesn't come to mind.   My sense is that the word you are looking for is ***jaded***. If this is the case, then the question would be reworded with a formulation along the lines of "but with ***having had*** lots to do / lots of experience."

[Oxford Online Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jaded)

> Bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something.
>   ‘meals to tempt the most jaded appetites’

[Macmillan English Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jaded)

> no longer enthusiastic or excited about things, especially because you have been disappointed by your many experiences of them

Comment: Is there a less formal version of this? *Jaded* isn't a word I'd expect to use as an informal statement.

Comment: Why do you think it is "formal?"

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking for a single word, not a phrase?

Comment: I'm classing formal as [not natural language](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/formal-language) in the spoken mode.

Comment: A phrase, preferably idiomatic is acceptable, depending on what it is...

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now, but your linked definition of "formal language," contrasting with "natural language," is completely different.

Comment: Thanks for following through and responding to the comments.  I've been on this site for a few weeks now, and have noticed that quite a few people don't bother.

Comment: this is the bit I was thinking of: *a language designed for use in situations in which natural language is unsuitable* - I agree that it isn't a great definition though...

Comment: Such as a computer language.  The definition is about what's called a "formal" and created or "designed" language as opposed to one used by human beings.